# Convert string to date Format string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

How can I convert format of a date string `DDMMYYYY` (ex: `31012010`) to `DD/MM/YY` (ex: `31/01/2010`) in SQL server 2008?

Answer (score 2):

Try [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259350%28SQL.80%29.aspx):

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(your_string_column, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/')
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(10), CAST(MyColumn AS datetime), 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

This extracts the date from a string that is followed by a space.
This took me awhile to figure out so I thought I'd share:

```
SELECT reference, Convert(date,Left(history,charindex(
    ' ',Left(history,12)) - 1)) as theDate
FROM productinfo
Order BY theDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I ended up here in Feb 2018, so...

In `SQL Server 2012`+ consider `Format`
- ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql (B and D)

For `2008` and above:

```
declare @d char(8)
 -- string manipulation assumes clean data
set @d = '31012010'

SELECT LEFT(@d, 2) +'/'+ SUBSTRING(@d, 3, 2) +'/'+ RIGHT(@d, 4)  As [with slashes]
```

String manipulation can be inefficient - make sure you understand the impact.
E.g. you would never put this code in a join clause (*may be* okay on a reporting server).

Personal opinion: the answer from Mark Byers `STUFF(STUFF(@d, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/'))` certainly works, but I think it is less maintainable if you have non-DBAs working in your code.  (`STUFF` ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql)